# Mongodb Spring MVC

Tags: mongodb, model-view-controller

Does someone know how spring mvc handle nested arrays in mongodb please?
Each time I add an arraylist to my model, at the first hit  I got an error and then I press F5 to refresh my page and it works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for your comment. Here is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048169/mongodb-and-spring-mvc-nested-documents I tried everything but can't figure it out